# Is there a pure CSS solution for Flexbox in IE 9 (IE 8)?

Tags: css, flexbox, modernizr

I have been using Flexbox to auto align a menu which works great, I really like this CSS feature. However, the menu obviously doesn't work in IE8 and actually disappears in IE 9.

Are there any pure CSS solutions rather than using Javascript and perhaps something called Modernizer I have seen?

```css
                #cssmenu ul {
                -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                -webkit-flex-direction: row;
                -ms-flex-direction: row;
                flex-direction: row;
                -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
                -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
                justify-content: space-around;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                }
                /* Default CSS from Shop stylesheet */
                #cssmenu,
                #cssmenu ul,
                #cssmenu ul li,
                #cssmenu ul li a,
                #cssmenu #menu-button {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                list-style: none;
                line-height: 1;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                }
```

```html
            <div id="cssmenu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="/menu1">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/menu2">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/menu3">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/menu4">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/menu5">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/menu6">Menu 6</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: #cssmenu is missing in your code ...  fallback will be display table/table-cell witout wrapping or float or inline-block.

Comment: You can put everything to tables - this will work similarly to flex box functionality